# Live sass compiler ubuntu

Tags: compiling, xampp, web-development

When I was on windows I used to use [Prepros](https://prepros.io/), a tool to compile LESS, Sass
with built in server for cross browser testing along with XAMPP. Now since I am switching my developing enviroment to Ubuntu, I am concerned about the way handled, on which I request some guided information about through Ubuntu.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could use [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/)

Answer (score 1):

You can install Koala from [this site](http://koala-app.com/)

> Koala is a GUI application for LESS, Sass and CoffeeScript compilation, to help web developers use these tools more efficiently for development.

Answer (score 0):

[Prepros](https://prepros.io/) is available for Linux too.

Here is the download page: https://prepros.io/downloads

Comment: why down vote? uh?